# MYSQL select DISTINCT values in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select distinct values in a database. Let me run you through a quick example.

Table:

```
foo bar
--- ---
a   c
c   f
d   a
c   a
f   c
a   c
d   a
a   c
c   a
f   c
```

Right, let's say my SQL is `SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar from table`. These are my results:

```
foo bar
--- ---
a   c
c   f
d   a
c   a
f   c
```

However the problem is is that there are repetitions of `a c` / `c a` just that they are in a different order. I don't want to select these, I want distinct values from both columns, please help!

Comment: Is this a question that you have been asked in some interview. :P

Comment: Not upvoting this question as selected answer is scaring me

Answer (score 50, accepted):

very very wicked & evil:

```
select distinct
    least(foo, bar) as value1
  , greatest(foo, bar) as value2
from table
```

Comment: This request is evil. foo can be in value1 as well as in value2. (Just tested it)

Comment: Doesn't work properly. My first select returned a tuple such as `(5, 108)` - the second number would be such big of an aberration, I had to check the record was really there. 

I ran a select and it wasn't.

Comment: I have a solution for this problem Buffalo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848228/8883361

Answer (score 98):

How about using GROUP BY?

`SELECT foo,bar FROM my_table GROUP BY foo,bar`

Comment: This is by far the better solution!

Comment: Absolutely a much better answer.

Comment: How could it be? This is not a right answer. Grouping just [foo=A, bar=C] and [foo=C, bar=A] by "foo,bar" will result in TWO rows. While OP wants single row in this case.

Answer (score 7):

How about :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.foo,a.bar 
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b ON a.foo=b.bar and a.bar=b.foo
WHERE b.foo IS NULL AND b.bar IS NULL
```

Output :

```
foo bar
--- ---
d   a
```

Comment: @KevinBurton `foo` and `bar` in `WHERE` clause are ambiguous

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for something that's the opposite of a symmetric closure (I don't know if it has a special name; antisymmetric something, since it's not a closure). For closures and closure like things where you need to compare two different columns, you can use joins. To make sure you don't filter out both rows when they are duplicated across columns, you need to a way to differentiate the repeats and include one of them, such as by including the pair where the first is the lesser.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.foo, t1.bar
  FROM `table` t1
    LEFT JOIN `table` t2
      ON t1.foo=t2.bar AND t1.bar=t2.foo 
  WHERE t2.foo IS NULL OR t1.foo <= t1.bar;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to the OP. Is there a link to a good tutorial and explanation available? Since we're not sure on the terminology I'm struggling to locate on on the net.

Answer (score 4):

```
   SELECT 
       foo, bar
   FROM tableX
   WHERE foo <= bar
 UNION 
   SELECT 
       bar, foo
   FROM tableX
   WHERE bar < foo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar FROM table WHERE
CONCAT(',',foo,bar,) NOT IN ( SELECT CONCAT(',',bar,foo) FROM table )
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
LEAST(sub.foo, sub.bar) as value_1
, GREATEST(sub.foo, sub.bar) as value_2

FROM
(SELECT
a.foo
,a.bar
FROM
table a
JOIN
table b
on a.foo = b.bar
and a.bar = b.foo) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So what I understood you want to combine 2 fields into a single SQL search result rows... I found most answers here very confusing.

This is the way I always do it when I have to (can be scaled up with multiple rows and multiple tables):

```sql
SELECT a.field1 FROM (<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT foo AS field1 FROM tableX<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UNION<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT bar AS field1 FROM tableX<br>
) a

OR

SELECT DISTINCT a.field1 FROM (<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT foo AS field1, conditions FROM tableX<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UNION ALL<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT bar AS field1, conditions FROM tableX<br>
) a WHERE a.conditions=1 (added extra conditions to filter out some results)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think found the best way:**

```
(SELECT distinct col1 as smth FROM table) UNION (SELECT distinct col2 as smth FROM table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause and 'not in' with a tuple, to filter out the situations where foo and bar are flipped. Like this:

```
select distinct foo, bar from table where (foo, bar) not in (select bar, foo from table);
```