# How to group by two columns in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to list all a conversation pairs in my database. I've table `message` where have store about message info.
 I've also tried this but not work for me [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744759/mysql-select-distinct-values-in-two-columns) becasue distinct select only columns specified. 

Ex. When `$_SESSION['userid'] = 1`

table message

```
sender_id   sendto_id    created(datetime)
1           2
1           2
1           3
1           4
3           1
3           1
2           4
4           2
```

My result have a reputations, between `1,3` and `3,1`.

```
sender_id   sendto_id
1           2
1           3
1           4
3           1
```

I just want like this and let's it chooses newest added field for each pairs.
Ex. `1-2(1)`,`1-2(2)` and `2-1` it should be `2-1` if `2-1` is newest or `1-2(2)` if it newest.

```
sender_id   sendto_id   created(datetime)
2           1           newest of pair 1-2 or 2-1
1           3           newest of pair 1-2 or 2-1
1           4           newest of pair 1-2 or 2-1
```

And my SQL here, please help! thank you.

```
select m.*,
       (select MAX(created)
          from message n
         where (n.senderid = m.sendtoid AND n.sendtoid = '$userid')
            OR (n.senderid = '$userid' AND n.sendtoid = m.sendtoid)) lastsend
  from message m
 where (m.senderid = '$userid' OR m.sendtoid = '$userid')
 group by m.senderid, m.sendtoid
 order by lastsend desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select least(sender_id, sendto_id) as sender_id,
       greatest(sender_id, sendto_id) as sendto_id,
       min(created_datetime)
from message m
group by least(sender_id, sendto_id), greatest(sender_id, sendto_id);
```

Comment: Yeah, but not work what's wrong?
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as sender_id, greatest(sender_id, sendto_id)' at line 4`

Comment: @Marcus . . . `as` doesn't belong in the `group by` clause, copy-and-paste error.