# Selecting multiple tables with matching columns but only displaying unique results

Tags: mysql

Here is my existing SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  par.WorkOrder,
  l.Address,
  l.Subdivision,
  eml.MailDate,
  lp.WorkDate
FROM
  parsed AS par
  LEFT JOIN emails AS eml      ON eml.EmailID = par.OriginID
  LEFT JOIN list AS l          ON par.WorkOrder = l.WorkOrder
  LEFT JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.WorkOrder = lp.WorkOrder
WHERE
  par.Status != 0 
  AND l.Completed = 0
  AND (lp.WorkDate IS NOT NULL OR eml.MailDate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
  par.WorkOrder
```

Right now it will only select WorkOrder matches from the parsed table. How can I also have it select WorkOrder from the locateparsed table and combine them? The best way to describe this would be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT par.WorkOrder OR lp.WorkOrder FROM....
```

UPDATE:

Here is the completed query I am using. I just need to sort out an issue with dates now of results that come up uncompleted that were mistakenly entered.

```
SELECT
  temp.WorkOrder,
  l.Address,
  l.Subdivision,
  eml.MailDate,
  temp.WorkDate
FROM (
    (SELECT par.WorkOrder, lp.WorkDate, par.OriginID, par.Status
    FROM parsed AS par
    LEFT JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.WorkOrder = lp.WorkOrder)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT lp.WorkOrder, lp.WorkDate, par.OriginID, '1' AS Status
    FROM parsed AS par
    RIGHT JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.WorkOrder = lp.WorkOrder
    WHERE par.WorkOrder IS NULL)
    ) AS temp
  LEFT JOIN emails AS eml      ON eml.EmailID = temp.OriginID
  LEFT JOIN list AS l          ON temp.WorkOrder = l.WorkOrder
WHERE
  (temp.Status != 0 OR eml.Parsed IS NULL)
  AND l.Completed = 0
  AND (temp.WorkDate IS NOT NULL OR eml.MailDate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
  temp.WorkOrder
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  As written, your `outer join` is negated for most tables with the `where` criteria.  Perhaps you're looking to use `union` -- difficult to say without sample data...

Comment: Seeing the output would be pretty confusing so ill try to explain best whats happening.

I have a parsed table and a locatesparsed table, both containing a "WorkOrder" column. The way it is setup now it selects from the parsed table and then joins a couple other tables. The issue I am facing is where a WorkOrder result is in the locatesparsed table but not in parsed therefore its negated and wont be shown in my results. Thats why I am looking for some sort of OR statement in the SELECT.

Comment: Maybe FULL OUTER JOIN or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6744815/1151408 can help you

Comment: If you stick DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query, there's a fair chance you're heading off track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT par.WorkOrder` and `GROUP BY par.WorkOrder` will accomplish the same thing, so you don't need to use both.

As Yuri suggested, use a full outer join:

```
SELECT
  temp.WorkOrder,
  l.Address,
  l.Subdivision,
  eml.MailDate,
  temp.WorkDate
FROM (
    (SELECT par.WorkOrder, lp.WorkDate, par.OriginID, par.Status
    FROM parsed AS par
    LEFT JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.WorkOrder = lp.WorkOrder)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT lp.WorkOrder, lp.WorkDate, par.OriginID, '1' AS Status
    FROM parsed AS par
    RIGHT JOIN locateparsed AS lp ON par.WorkOrder = lp.WorkOrder
    WHERE par.WorkOrder IS NULL)
    ) AS temp
  LEFT JOIN emails AS eml      ON eml.EmailID = temp.OriginID
  LEFT JOIN list AS l          ON temp.WorkOrder = l.WorkOrder
WHERE
  temp.Status != 0 
  AND l.Completed = 0
  AND (temp.WorkDate IS NOT NULL OR eml.MailDate IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
  temp.WorkOrder
```

Note: In order to include the results from `locateparsed`, I added `'1' AS Status`, otherwise the `WHERE` condition would exclude all rows from `locateparsed` without a matching WorkOrder in `parsed`.

Comment: Strange.. Unknown column 'lp.WorkDate' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry, `lp` should be `temp` of course. But that `WHERE` condition kind of defeats the purpose of the outer join. If you gave a table with desired output I could help better.

Comment: Thanks, it's working like I wanted from what I can tell. The only issue I am facing now has to do with dates so I'll try to sort that myself.