# MySQL get unique values from 2 columns + get row of highest 3th column when duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to start by telling that this is a really specific question. It's also highly related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837560/6033440). There they use:

```
SELECT foo,bar FROM my_table GROUP BY foo,bar
```

But what differentiates this question against the linked one is when a dupplicate is found; an arbitrary row of the duplicates is returned. I need to get the row with the highest value of a third column. 
For example:

```
a b 20
a b 10
a a 2
b b 10
b b 29
c c 2
c c 4
c c 9
```

Desired output:

```
a b 20
b b 29
c c 9
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `max`? `select foo, bar, max(col3)...`

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you very much! How can I mark this as answer?