# Mysql Retrieving Two Columns As One Distinct or Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

I am stumped with a mysql query.  I am attempting to bring back all unique values from two columns sorted by date.  Here is my table:

```
from                to               body      created_on
+55555555555        +22222222222     hello     2015-03-20 01:00:00
+11111111111        +33333333333     hello     2015-03-21 01:00:00
+33333333333        +44444444444     hello     2015-03-18 01:00:00
+66666666666        +11111111111     hello     2015-03-12 01:00:00
+11111111111        +77777777777     hello     2015-03-05 01:00:00
```

Basically it is a table that stores sms messages and I want to pull back the 100 most recent phone numbers that have entries into the sms table. So something like this:

```
number
+11111111111
+77777777777
+66666666666
+22222222222
+33333333333
```

Another requirement is that I don't pull bring back the phone numbers +4444444444 and +555555555555 because they are administrator numbers.  The numbers should also be sorted by date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT `from` as num, created_at FROM sms WHERE `from` NOT IN (+4444444444, +5555555555)
GROUP BY num
UNION
SELECT `to` as num, created_at FROM sms WHERE `to` NOT IN (+4444444444, +5555555555)
GROUP BY num
ORDER BY created_at
```

I know I'm close but it's bringing back duplicates which I don't want.

Comment: Can you provide at least enough data to see the duplicates ? I've trying this and can't see any duplicates using you data

Comment: Duplicates will be present in his query, since they are Union of two not related result sets

Comment: Yup, got something wrong, forget my previous comment.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744759/mysql-select-distinct-values-in-two-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `MAX` initially in the two queries of the `UNION` operation so as to get the most recent date per number. The apply it once more on the whole set and order by date in descending order with a `LIMIT` clause to get the 100 most recent numbers:

```
SELECT num, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
FROM (
  SELECT `from` as num, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
  FROM sms 
  WHERE `from` NOT IN (+4444444444, +5555555555)
  GROUP BY num

  UNION

  SELECT `to` as num, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
  FROM sms 
  WHERE `to` NOT IN (+4444444444, +5555555555)
  GROUP BY num) AS t
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Interesting use of the subquery inside the FROM.  I ran it on a table with 7000 rows with no limit and it only took 0.06s on my local machine.  I also modified it slightly to have the admin numbers in a separate table `admin_number` and use another subquery so i switched  `WHERE \`from\` NOT IN (+4444444444, +5555555555)` to `WHERE \`from\` NOT IN (SELECT admin_number.number FROM admin_number)`

Comment: @WarrenR Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this or any other answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.