# Can't join two tables in one with two unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to **select all unique UK cities, where customers and suppliers live, sort from A to Z**

I have two tables: **Customers** and **Suppliers**. They both have **City** and **Country** columns.

This is my request:

```
select distinct Customers.City, Suppliers.City, Customers.Country, Suppliers.Country
from Customers
join Suppliers
on Customers.Country = Suppliers.Country
where Customers.Country like "UK";
```

And as a result I get 4 columns: City, City, Country, Country.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're getting 4 columns because you're asking for 4 columns.  I'm unclear on what you want.  "Show me the cities/countries of suppliers that also have a customer within that same city and country?"

Comment: You don't want a JOIN you want a UNION

Comment: I need unique UK cities from two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use least and greatest clause for that.
Below answer may help you.
[MYSQL select DISTINCT values in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744759/mysql-select-distinct-values-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Here is right request that works:

```
select City,Country
from Customers
where Country like "UK"
union
select City,Country
from Suppliers
where Country like "UK"
order by City asc;
```

Comment: you don't need LIKE but =. A good SQL primer would probably help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like